# Bootstrap glyphicons not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have this html page:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "images/favicon.ico" %}"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static "css/bootstrap-theme.css" %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static "fonts/font-awesome.min.css" %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static "css/custom.css" %}" media="screen">

    <script src="{% static "js/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/added.js" %}"></script>
[...]
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" id="like" name="{{post.id}}"> </i>
```

the thumbs up icon does not display, neither on Chrome nor on Firefox, despite the fact that all the css files are loaded and bootstrap css is rendered ok.

I looked at simillar questions on SO but could not find my answer. So appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280)?

Answer (score 0):

The font file isn't being loaded correctly. Check if the files are in their expected location.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

If that doesn't work, i recommend to you to re-download bootstrap files and make sure that all files are copied and in the correct path.

Comment: Will you please elaborate why they are not loaded correctly?

Comment: This part: `url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')` do you have the fonts on that path?